# Installing ClipBucket but installation cannot find ffmpeg

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg

I am running the installation of ClipBucket and I have installed ffmpeg. I rerun the installation to refresh the requirements and it continues to show:

```
Unable to find ffmpeg
```

If I do a find of ffmpeg, I find it though:

```
:~$ sudo find / -type f -name "ffmpeg"
/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with Plesk. Do I need to do something with Plesk for this to be seen by the web page?

I am not a pro when it comes to Ubuntu so I'm not sure where to look not or what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that you have installed FFmpeg in a location that ClipBucket *does not look*. I do not know ClipBucket at all but there are [instructions here](http://docs.clip-bucket.com/ffmpeg#how_to_get_ffmpeg_path) for adding in a non-standard `$PATH`.

If this does not work you need to add the location of FFmpeg to your `$PATH`, and you should really do this anyway on a well setup system. There are 2 options:

**1. Change the *local* $PATH:**

Add the following to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ffmpeg/bin
```

Then run the following command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

But this will only have effect for an individual user, you may very well need to make a *system* change to affect *all users*:

**2. Change the *system* $PATH:**

Add the following to your `/etc/environment` file:

```
:/opt/ffmpeg/bin
```

Add this to the end of the existing `$PATH` statement so that the whole line will look something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/ffmpeg/bin"
```

You will need to use `sudo` and your favorite editor to edit this file and don't forget to log out and back in for this to take effect.

**3. Testing:**

I tested these changes on my own system, the results can be seen with either technique by using the following command:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/ffmpeg/bin
andrew@corinth:~
```

And you can see that now your `$PATH` is extended and your application should be able to see FFmpeg...

**Further Reading:**

- [ClipBucket Docs: FFMpeg](http://docs.clip-bucket.com/ffmpeg)

Comment: If I understand correctly, that will add it to my current user. Will that affect my Plesk where it will see it also?

Comment: Ok I did this with my current user, and it didn't affect the website. Am I suppose to do this under a different user?

Comment: @ConcernedCitizen Good point and here I am perhaps revealing my ignorance of Plex... I have added instructions to change the system $PATH and this might be enough. Let me know if this works out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. ClipBucket by default looks for ffmpeg in `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`. I worked around this by creating a symlink to the actual location.

For your location, it would be:

```
ln -s /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

For ffmpeg as installed by `apt-get` on Ubuntu, it would be:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

I created an Ansible role that automates the entire process of installing ClipBucket on Ubuntu, so you may be interested in trying that out:

http://mtlynch.io/ansible-role-clipbucket/